# ListView Items repeated in Custom Adapter

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I am trying to add dynamic textview to listview items.textviews can be of 1-2 or more than that depending on data I have succeed in adding the textview but problem is textviews are repeated on scroll.

I am creating new object of textview each time in loop.I am aware of the problem that android tries to reuse existing view but i have to add new view every time.

Here is my code in custom adapter:

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View View, ViewGroup parent){
    final int pos=groupPosition;
    ManfVsCatRow row=new ManfVsCatRow();

    LayoutInflater inflater= context.getLayoutInflater();       
    groupView=(TableLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.salessummarycatvsmanfgroup, null);     
//  groupView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(20,30,40));
    groupView.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.bg);


        groupView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(context.getlist().isGroupExpanded(pos))
                context.getlist().collapseGroup(pos);
            else
                context.getlist().expandGroup(pos);             
        }
    });

    ClosingStock clstock=new ClosingStock();
    TableRow tr=new TableRow(context);
    TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams=new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tr.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
    tr.setWeightSum(1.0f);



    TextView space=new TextView(context);
    space.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,.1f));
    tr.addView(space);      

    TextView manufacturerTextView=new TextView(context);
    manufacturerTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

    TableRow.LayoutParams categoryParams=new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,.35f);
    categoryParams.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 5);  

    manufacturerTextView.setLayoutParams(categoryParams);        
    manufacturerTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.LEFT);        
    try 
    {

    //  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        manufacturerTextView.setText(groups[groupPosition]);    
        row.setItemsValue(manufacturerTextView.getText().toString());
        rowList.add(row);
        tr.addView(manufacturerTextView);

        Log.e("ManufaturerTextView", String.valueOf(groups[groupPosition]));

        int[] spGroupTotals=getGroupStockPointTotals(groupPosition);
        int spGroupTotalsTotal=0;
        for(int i=0;i<spArray.length();i++)
        {
            spGroupTotalsTotal+=spGroupTotals[i];
        }   

        TableRow.LayoutParams totalParams=new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,.225f);
        totalParams.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 5);

        TextView tvTotal=new TextView(context);
        tvTotal.setLayoutParams(totalParams);
        tvTotal.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tvTotal.setText(String.valueOf(spGroupTotalsTotal));

        row=new ManfVsCatRow();
        row.setItemsValue(tvTotal.getText().toString());
        rowList.add(row);
        tr.addView(tvTotal);
        Log.e("SalesStockTextView", String.valueOf(spGroupTotalsTotal));


        TableRow.LayoutParams closingStockParams=new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,.225f);
        closingStockParams.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 5);

        TextView closingStockTextView=new TextView(context);
        closingStockTextView.setLayoutParams(closingStockParams);
        closingStockTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        closingStockTextView.setText(getGroupClosingStock(groupPosition));


        row=new ManfVsCatRow();
        row.setItemsValue(closingStockTextView.getText().toString());
        rowList.add(row);
        tr.addView(closingStockTextView);
        Log.e("CLosing TextVIew",String.valueOf(getGroupClosingStock(groupPosition)));

    //  size++;

        groupView.addView(tr);


       for(int y=0;y<rowList.size();y++)
       {

           Log.e("Intern Here",String.valueOf(rowList.get(y)));

       }


        TextView spaceTextView=new TextView(context);
        spaceTextView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,.1f));




    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }
```

Comment: I think you need to make use "groupPosition" value to return view that renders data only for that position.  Since you are not using it, I am guessing you are seeing same thing in all positions.

Comment: @WandMaker so how can i use it by code?Actually i am new in android.So can you please tell me in a elaborate form?

Comment: As far as I know, you use when you have list of items to display.  So, this list comes from an array as in case of ArrayAdapter or from DB as in case of CursorAdapter.  Now, the list view will call your adapter when it requires to render item N, and so you should create a View corresponding to Nth item.

Comment: See if this article helps you understand it better http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html